C# WPF | Обрезается изображение
Пишу приложение на C#, используя WPF. Из библиотек подключена только "MaterialDesign XAML".
Я создаю кнопку, и внутри хочу добавить изображение(иконку), которая по размерам меньше кнопки, но она обрезается, как будто границы кнопки сильно уменьшены.
Вот такой код у меня:
XAML:
<Button Width="32" Height="32" Margin="-170,18,0,0" materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius="13">
    <StackPanel Width="100" Height="32" Margin="-16,-4,0,0">
        <Image Source="/resources/emailIcon.png" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="-66,6,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>

И я получаю вот такое:

То есть, почему то часть иконки просто обрезана, типо не вмещается в кнопку, хотя всё отлично должно помещаться по размеру.



Растровые изображения для кнопкок - зло. В интернете полно векторной графики, да и вы без проблем можете сделать ее самостоятельно. 2. Вы ведь сами обрезаете изображение через Margin. 3. Это все надо делать через стили, а не через вкладывание контента.


EvgeniyZ, я в стилях не очень разбираюсь, был бы благодарен если бы написали в ответах пример стиля

Ох, знали бы, сколько таких ответов уже было дано) Да и в документации все подробно сказано как и что делать. Ну вот к примеру, полноценная кнопка с векторным крестиком внутри, даже с анимацией.

@EvgeniyZ спасибо большое)
